# Is it possible to change the size of variable labels in biplot (MATLAB)?

Tags: matlab, variables, plot, pca

I've done PCA on my data set and now I'm trying to visualise it using biplot in MATLAB. Three of my variables are almost collinear with almost the same length, so that their labels overlap. I would like to rectify this by perhaps changing the size of the labels. I couldn't find anything helpful in the documentation pertaining to biplot, does anyone have any ideas as to how to do this ? Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: Have you tried:
figure
set(gca,'fontsize',18)
hold on
biplot(coefs)
hold off

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I tried specifying fontsize in biplot  and I got an error. Is this different from that ? (Sorry, I'm a MATLAB novice).

Comment: This will set the fontsize for all strings in your figure. You pretty much want to get the handles from the figure you produced (gca) and then set the font size.

Comment: @Flynn: Please [don't answer questions in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) and format your code correctly.

Comment: update : I tried the solution of @Flynn, to no effect. It removed my axis labels and the change in font only affects the axes tick labels.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
biplot(...'varlabels',vbls,'Fontsize',18);
```

Or

```
h=get(gca,'varlabels')
set(h, 'FontSize', 18)
```

Or

```
figureHandle = gcf;
set(findall(figureHandle,'type','text'),'fontSize',18)
```

Or manually change it in your figure settings, and then produce the code that way.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for answering. I tried all three, but none of those worked. But I managed to change the font by doing:  `set(0, 'defaultTextFontSize',8)`